# What is this called and how can i create something similar in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I was seeing some application and saw this application i was wondering how they created this horizontal navigation menu for their android application.

[image]

So what is this horizontal navigation called in android?? and can any one point me to any resource which has some sample example for creating 1 for android?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the top is an *accordion* layout. See this related question: [Android - accordion widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161999/android-accordion-widget).

The control bar at the bottom is just 4 styled buttons next to each other.

Comment: Hi thanks for the accordion menu i want to know about the horizontal bar are you sure they are button?? placed aside each other?? Because when i am clicking it opens another activity with still the horizontal bar below

Comment: What you are talking about _is_ effectively a tab layout -- a set of buttons which changes the content of an attached frame.  The frame contents may all be controlled by one activity or may be a set of "sub-activities".  This is what tab layouts do in Android and other GUI frameworks.  That said, many people hate the default tab layout that comes with Android and modify it or completely re-implement it.  A google search for "android custom tabwidget" would get you started there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want a ListView.

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Answer (score 0):

That is a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) in Android.

Please see [the tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) provided on Android's site.

Comment: I think the OP means the horizontal element at the bottom, not the ListView

Comment: In that case, maybe just a linear or tab layout. Whatever you're looking for, OP, try taking a look at some of these Android view tutorials: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Comment: its not tab layout i went through linear layout earlier but i was trying to imitate something similar i am talking about the horizontal bar

Comment: Pranay - You could implement a TabHost and bottom align it by settings it's orientation.     e.g.   orientation(TabHost.Orientation.BOTTOM)