# Android scale animation on view

Tags: android, animation

I want to use ScaleAnimation (programmatically not in xml) to change height to view from 0 to 60% of parent height. Width of view is constant  and is 50px. View is empty only background color is set.

Can someone give me code for `scaleAnim` using ScaleAnimation from code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layContainer
    >
<View  
    android:layout_width="50px" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/viewContainer" 
    android:background:"#00f00"
    />

</LinearLayout>


ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(...);
```

[image: view before and after animation]

view before and after animation
.Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Here is a code snip to do exactly that.

```
public void scaleView(View v, float startScale, float endScale) {
    Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            1f, 1f, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            startScale, endScale, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f); // Pivot point of Y scaling
    anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

The ScaleAnimation constructor used here takes 8 args, 4 related to handling the X-scale which we don't care about `(1f, 1f, ... Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, ...)`.

The other 4 args are for the Y-scaling we do care about.

`startScale, endScale` - In your case, you'd use `0f, 0.6f`.

`Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f` - This specifies where the shrinking of the view collapses to (referred to as the pivot in the documentation). Here, we set the float value to `1f` because we want the animation to start growing the bar from the bottom. If we wanted it to grow downward from the top, we'd use `0f`.

Finally, and equally important, is the call to `anim.setFillAfter(true)`. If you want the result of the animation to stick around after the animation completes, you must run this on the animator before executing the animation.

So in your case, you can do something like this:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.viewContainer);
scaleView(v, 0f, .6f);
```

Comment: I wan't to have this as efficient as possible, therefor I want to use a ViewPropertyAnimator. How do I do this with a ViewPropertyAnimator? I can't figure out how to correctly specify a starting position for the animation, and relative positioning seems impossible (which would be best, because then I could reuse my some what complicated coordinates)

Answer (score 63):

In XML, this what I use for achieving the same result. May be this is more intuitive.

**`scale_up.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

**`scale_down.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```

See the animation on the X axis is from `1.0 -> 1.0` which means you don't have any scaling up in that direction and stays at the full width while, on the Y axis you get `0.0 -> 1.0` scaling, as shown in the graphic in the question. Hope this helps someone.

**Some might want to know the java code as we see one requested.**

Place the animation files in `anim` folder and then load and set animation files something like.

```
Animation scaleDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(youContext, R.anim.scale_down);
ImagView v = findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
v.startAnimation(scaleDown);
```

Comment: Why is the animation also pivoting the view?

Answer (score 51):

try this code to create Scale animation without using xml

```
ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(fromXscale, toXscale, fromYscale, toYscale, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

Comment: thanks for answer but `(from, to, from, to, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5)` is my problem :)

Comment: my real problem is fromXscale, toXscale, fromYscale, toYscale and pivot values of variables, thanks

Answer (score 40):

Use this method (**No need to xml file**)

If you want **scale** to quarter(half x,half y)

```
view.animate().scaleX(0.5f).scaleY(0.5f)
```

If you want **scale** and move to bottom right

```
view.animate().scaleX(0.5f).scaleY(0.5f)
        .translationY((view.height/4).toFloat()).translationX((view.width/4).toFloat())
```

If you want move to **top** use `(-view.height/4)` and for **left** (-view.width/4)

If you want do something **after animation ends** use `withEndAction(Runnable runnable)` function.

You can use some other property like **alpha** and **rotation**

**Full code**

```
view.animate()
      .scaleX(0.5f).scaleY(0.5f)//scale to quarter(half x,half y)
      .translationY((view.height/4).toFloat()).translationX((view.width/4).toFloat())// move to bottom / right
      .alpha(0.5f) // make it less visible
      .rotation(360f) // one round turns
      .setDuration(1000) // all take 1 seconds
      .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              //animation ended
           }
      });
```

Comment: simpler than other solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

Resize using **helper methods** and **start-repeat-end handlers** like this:

```
resize(
    view1,
    1.0f,
    0.0f,
    1.0f,
    0.0f,
    0.0f,
    0.0f,
    150,
    null,
    null,
    null);

  return null;
}
```

Helper methods:

```
/**
 * Resize a view.
 */
public static void resize(
  View view,
  float fromX,
  float toX,
  float fromY,
  float toY,
  float pivotX,
  float pivotY,
  int duration) {

  resize(
    view,
    fromX,
    toX,
    fromY,
    toY,
    pivotX,
    pivotY,
    duration,
    null,
    null,
    null);
}

/**
 * Resize a view with handlers.
 *
 * @param view     A view to resize.
 * @param fromX    X scale at start.
 * @param toX      X scale at end.
 * @param fromY    Y scale at start.
 * @param toY      Y scale at end.
 * @param pivotX   Rotate angle at start.
 * @param pivotY   Rotate angle at end.
 * @param duration Animation duration.
 * @param start    Actions on animation start. Otherwise NULL.
 * @param repeat   Actions on animation repeat. Otherwise NULL.
 * @param end      Actions on animation end. Otherwise NULL.
 */
public static void resize(
  View view,
  float fromX,
  float toX,
  float fromY,
  float toY,
  float pivotX,
  float pivotY,
  int duration,
  Callable start,
  Callable repeat,
  Callable end) {

  Animation animation;

  animation =
    new ScaleAnimation(
      fromX,
      toX,
      fromY,
      toY,
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
      pivotX,
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
      pivotY);

  animation.setDuration(
    duration);

  animation.setInterpolator(
    new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

  animation.setFillAfter(true);

  view.startAnimation(
    animation);

  animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

      if (start != null) {
        try {

          start.call();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

      if (end != null) {
        try {

          end.call();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(
      Animation animation) {

      if (repeat != null) {
        try {

          repeat.call();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }  
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void expand(final View v) {
        ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(250);
        scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        v.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    }

    public void collapse(final View v) {
        ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(250);
        scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        v.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    }
```

Comment: your expand collapses, and your collapse expands?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on values anim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXScale="0.2"
        android:fromYScale="0.2"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

call on styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogScale">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/scale_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/scale_out</item>
</style>
```

In Java code:
set Onclick

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            fab_onclick(R.style.DialogScale, "Scale" ,(Activity) context,getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView());
          //  Dialogs.fab_onclick(R.style.DialogScale, "Scale");

        }
```

setup on method:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = type;
```