# Create animation when tap to slide up and push down to slide down android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-animation

In continuation of this similar type of effect, [Creating animation] ([Creating animation for images from small to large when scrolling vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472060/creating-animation-for-images-from-small-to-large-when-scrolling-vertical)) I need to tap to open the image instead of dragging the image till top and down. How to do that?
any idea?

```
private double scrollProgress = 0.0;
private double topViewScaleFactor = 2.0;
private double collapsedViewHeight = 200.0;
private double expandedViewHeight = 700.0;
private double scrollProgressPerView = expandedViewHeight;

private final ScrollTouchListener touchListener = new ScrollTouchListener() {
    @Override
    protected void onScroll(float x, float y) {
        scrollProgress += y;
        if(scrollProgress < 0.0) {
            scrollProgress = 0.0;
        }
```

This just makes scroll from image to top. I need to tap to open image. How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by tap open? I'm the one who answered the question you link to. I can help you modify the custom view I posted to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @XaverKapeller as in previous requiremment what you have done is, user needs to scroll image to top and vice versa for down also. But my requirement is in addition to that, 1. when user tap(clicks) the image, it should go up. 2.when you drag the image to 50% to top(it should not rest in that 50% itself) and leave, it should go up! similarly when you drag the image to down too.. i am struck to find solution for two days for this requirement :(

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but you are going to have to illustrate a little what you want it to look like. Otherwise I won't be able to really modify the custom view to suit your needs.

Comment: I don't have demo to show :(  since it has been implemented in IOS (Ultra visual app) https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ultravisual/id711280582?mt=8 however I will illustrate with this.for eg: in this gif image.(http://i.stack.imgur.com/vkq0k.gif) if tapped the image "scenario" or if moved 50%(this is just my assumption after seeing ios app) above means, it goes up very smooth automatically without user pushing till top and similarly for down too and also when clicked the image, it goes up. @XaverKapeller

Comment: I think I understand I will try to modify the view but give me a few hours to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I played around the custom view from the question you are linking to ([Creating animation for images from small to large when scrolling vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472060/creating-animation-for-images-from-small-to-large-when-scrolling-vertical)) and adding animations is pretty easy. The result looks like this:

[image: Scrolling]
[image: Clicking]

First we have to make the custom view snap to a certain item. For that we have to modify the `ScrollTouchListener` like this:

```
public abstract class ScrollTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private boolean touching = false;
    private boolean scrolling = false;
    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

    private double scrollPositionX = 0;
    private double scrollPositionY = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {


        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                touching = true;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touching = false;
                if(scrolling) {
                    scrolling = false;
                    onScrollEnded(scrollPositionX, scrollPositionY);
                } else {
                    onClick(x, y); 
                }
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                double newX = event.getX();
                double newY = event.getY();

                double difX =  x - newX;
                double difY =  y - newY;

                if (scrolling) {
                    performScroll(difX, difY);
                } else if(difX > 0 || difY > 0)  {
                    scrolling = true;
                    onScrollStarted(scrollPositionX, scrollPositionY);
                    performScroll(difX, difY);
                }

                x = newX;
                y = newY;
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void onScrollStarted(double scrollPositionX, double scrollPositionY);
    protected abstract void onScroll(double scrollPositionX, double scrollPositionY, double deltaX, double deltaY);
    protected abstract void onScrollEnded(double scrollPositionX, double scrollPositionY);
    protected abstract void onClick(double x, double y);

    private void performScroll(double difX, double difY) {
        scrollPositionX += difX;
        scrollPositionY += difY;

        onScroll(scrollPositionX, scrollPositionY, difX, difY);
    }

    public double getScrollPositionX() {
        return scrollPositionX;
    }

    public void setScrollPositionX(double scrollPositionX) {
        this.scrollPositionX = scrollPositionX;
    }

    public double getScrollPositionY() {
        return scrollPositionY;
    }

    public void setScrollPositionY(double scrollPositionY) {
        this.scrollPositionY = scrollPositionY;
    }
}
```

Essentially I just added callback for `onScrollStarted()` which is called when the user starts scrolling - in this case we don't need that - and `onScrollEnded()` which is called when the user stops scrolling. I moved the responsibility of keeping track of the scroll progress to the `ScrollTouchListener` for convenience and I also added getters and setters so we can modify the scroll progress if we need to - in our case so the views can snap into a certain position. Another thing I added is click detection in the form of the `onClick` callback. We need that so we can click a view to make it expand. We can't use a normal `OnClickListener` for this because we are adding a `OnTouchListener` in our case the `ScrollTouchListener` which consumes all touch events and so  click listeners stop working. But the click detection is not perfect as it is implemented there. The main problem is that a click only counts if you do not move your finger. If you move your finger even by only one pixel it already counts as a scroll. There should be some extra logic here that you can move your finger by a few pixel and it still counts as a click, if necessary this can be implemented later.

Then in the custom view we add a calculation to the implementation of the `onScroll()` method in the `ScrollTouchListener` which calculates the index of the currently expanded view and of the first visible view at the top:

```
double relativeScroll = scrollPositionY / scrollProgressPerView;
currentItemIndex = (int)Math.round(relativeScroll);
```

`currentItemIndex` is a member variables of the custom view. After that add the implementation of the `onScrollEnded()` and `onClick()` methods. All we do there is calculate the how far the custom view should be scrolled. Either to snap to a certain item or to scroll to the clicked item:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollEnded(double scrollPositionX, double scrollPositionY) {
    scrollProgress = currentItemIndex * scrollProgressPerView + 1;
    setScrollPositionY(scrollProgress);
    updateChildViews();
}

@Override
protected void onClick(double x, double y) {
    int clickedIndex = (int) Math.round((getScrollPositionY() + y) / scrollProgressPerView) + 1;
    scrollProgress = clickedIndex * scrollProgressPerView + 1;
    setScrollPositionY(scrollProgress);
    updateChildViews();
}
```

And that's it. This is all you need to enable the snapping and the selecting of `Views`. As a result the whole implementation of the `ScrollTouchListener` in the custom view should look something like this:

```
private final ScrollTouchListener touchListener = new ScrollTouchListener() {

    @Override
    protected void onScrollStarted(double scrollPositionX, double scrollPositionY) {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScroll(double scrollPositionX, double scrollPositionY, double deltaX, double deltaY) {
        scrollProgress += deltaY;
        if(scrollProgress < 0.0) {
            scrollProgress = 0.0;
        }

        if(scrollProgress > maxScrollProgress) {
            scrollProgress = maxScrollProgress;
        }

        double relativeScroll = scrollPositionY / scrollProgressPerView;
        currentItemIndex = (int)Math.round(relativeScroll);

        updateChildViews();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollEnded(double scrollPositionX, double scrollPositionY) {
        scrollProgress = currentItemIndex * scrollProgressPerView + 1;
        setScrollPositionY(scrollProgress);
        updateChildViews();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick(double x, double y) {
        int clickedIndex = (int) Math.round((getScrollPositionY() + y) / scrollProgressPerView) + 1;
        scrollProgress = clickedIndex * scrollProgressPerView + 1;
        setScrollPositionY(scrollProgress);
        updateChildViews();
    }
};
```

You might wonder know where the actual animation stuff comes in, but we actually don't have to take care of that. There is one very convenient feature that handles all the animation for us. You just need to add this to attribute to the custom view in the xml layout:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

For example the layout I used for testing purposes looked like this:

```
<at.test.app.customviews.accordion.view.Accordion xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               android:src="@drawable/alpen"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               android:src="@drawable/alpen"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               android:src="@drawable/alpen"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               android:src="@drawable/alpen"/>

</at.test.app.customviews.accordion.view.Accordion>
```

Notice the `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` I added to the custom view. That is all you need to get this view to animate any layout change.