# Creating animation for images from small to large when scrolling vertical using Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

For reference please see the link given below. I want this feature for IOS using objective.

[Creating animation for images from small to large when scrolling vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472060/creating-animation-for-images-from-small-to-large-when-scrolling-vertical)

Thanks in advance

Comment: @NitinGohel That is for `Android` not iOS.You have to use `UICollectionView` with `UIKit Dynamics`, see a good example with tutorial [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/collection-views-and-uidynamics/)

Comment: Paul Hegarty does some great lectures on iTunes U. His last using objective c are for iOS 7 although still relevant.  The end of lecture 8 and start of lecture 9 gave me a good basis to begin to understand how to animate objects in objective c. [CS193P Fall 2013 by Stanford](https://itun.es/au/gCOUR)