# Collapsing CardView inside RecyclerView when animating

Tags: android, android-animation, android-cardview

### What I'm trying to do

I have a `CardView` with a supporting text on the bottom that is `GONE` by default. I want to make this section of the card visible only when the user clicks the "action arrow", as shown on the image below:

[image: Expand Arrow]

I know I can achieve that by simply setting that `View` visibility to `VISIBLE`, but I also want to animate the expand and the collapse events.

### The problem and what I've tried so far

To do that I've used the `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` property on my `CardView` xml, and it works just fine when it's expanding. But once I click on the arrow again to collapse the supporting text, the card below overlaps the card I've clicked during the animation. How can I avoid this overlapping?

**EDIT:** I know it may be possible to do something like the [solution on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414065/android-scale-animation-on-view), but it seems overly complicated since the `android:animateLayoutChanges` option exists. I wonder if it's possible to solve my issue using that XML property, to keep it simple.

My animation code is as follows:

**Java code**

```
protected void expandCard() {
    if (isExpanded) {
        ibt_show_more.animate().rotation(0).start();
        isExpanded = false;
        tv_support.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        ibt_show_more.animate().rotation(180).start();
        isExpanded = true;
        tv_support.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**XML code**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_small"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/os_list_item_cv">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/os_list_item_rl_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <!-- Here goes the header, the image, the action buttons and so on -->
        <!-- Omitted on purpose -->
        <!-- ... -->

        <!-- This is the support TextView -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_support"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/os_list_item_rl_actions"
            android:text="@string/bacon_ipsum"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

### GIF for completeness (With wrong collapse behavior)

[image]

Comment: instead android:animateLayoutChanges you can use custom animation. ex. scalling support text from 0 to 1 for expand and for collaps scale from 1 to 0

Comment: Care to write an example as an answer?

Comment: Can you post your animation code?

Comment: Posted the animation code.

Comment: please add the xml you are using for the layout animation

Comment: does it work if you change the RL height to wrap_content?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Right before you change the visibility, add this line of code:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(the rootView containing the cardView, new AutoTransition());
```

You should get a smooth animation. Also remove "animateLayoutChanges=true" from your xml before this.

As for why this works, calling TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition() makes the TransitionManger capture current values in the parent ViewGroup and render the animations in the next animation frame. The Transition passed in this case is an [AutoTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/AutoTransition.html), which takes care of all the fading, moving, and resizing in the parent ViewGroup.

See [Transitions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.html) and [TransitionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html)

Also take care to use Transitions from the support library where appropriate, or perform the neccessary API level checks.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation. Please do make a habit of doing this in all answers you post

Comment: I may add that it also works if I keep the `animateLayoutChanges=true"` if I put the `TransitionManager`  **only** when I set the visibility to `GONE`.

Comment: note that the `rootView` provided to the function should be the parent of all views that should be affected by the animation