# How to smooth the animation from loading to complete

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, loading, loading-animation

I have a progressBar(android default) and complete imageView

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

[image]
[image]

if i use `View.GONE` and `View.INVISIBLE`, it looks weird

[here is example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itOL5.jpg)

Is there have easy way to make it smooth?

Comment: make the tick visible with animation . probably 2 scale and alpha .. Use ViewPropertyAnimator .. its just one liner code .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54966765/4168607

Comment: @ADM Tick is part of image so i cant control it.

Comment: I meant animate whole image not just tick .. you will never know until you try it . And since you do not have any particular expected result so you need try these things whichever gives a better ux keep that one.

Answer (score 0):

I was referring to the answer from ashakirov on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648103/9261288 he uses Transition API, maybe you can try it to make your animation smoother.