# How to display data in android page using Accordion?

Tags: android

I need to **display details** of a customer. I need to use **Accordion** to display the details. Can anybody suggest how to do that in android? Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. There are a lot of ways to do it. For example visit [Android - accordion widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161999/android-accordion-widget) or http://android-puremvc-ormlite.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-simple-accordion-panel.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it. One way is to define a linear layout. Add different TextViews to signify the heading and the body.

Or, you can use [my Accordion View component](https://github.com/riyagayasen/Android_accordion_view) for your purpose. It already has the different components defined like the heading and the body. To add the UI elements to the body, simply add them in the XML file, the way you add elements to a RelativeLayout.

```
<com.riyagayasen.easyaccordion.AccordionView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:isAnimated="false"
    app:heading="This is a demo accordion"
    app:isExpanded="true"
    app:isPartitioned="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Demo accordion text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Button"
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Button 2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_2" />
</com.riyagayasen.easyaccordion.AccordionView>
```

This renders an accordion like this

[image: The demo accordion]