# how to expand a list in expanded list when user click on a button in the list

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a ExpandableListView containing groupviews and childviews. GroupViews contains 3 textviews and 2 imageviews. Onclick of the second imageview the grouprow should be expanded as well as child rows should displayed..

How Should I do this..? Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi here is the answer of you question find the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514606/how-to-display-data-in-android-page-using-accordion)

It is possible. There are a lot of ways to do it. For example visit Android - accordion widget