# Accordion like animation for android

Tags: android, animation

I need to build an accordion lie animation and I have no clue where to start.

Can you please address me to resources and sample codes so I can better understand how to do that?

The closest thing I saw on Android is the cord animation in Go Launcher, so I don't know if it is possible, anyway I'd glad to even be able to create something like Go's animation.

Thank you

You can see an example in this screenshot from the iPhone app 'task'
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56isCnonYqA&feature=player_embedded#t=38s

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161999/android-accordion-widget

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want an animation of accordion like, meaning the view will collapse into an accordion dragging the next view with it.