# how to insert a code accordion in another activity?

Tags: android, accordion, android-viewpager

I'm using a viewpaer in my application!
Where on one of the screens I need to insert an accordion view!

I found the code I need to use the accordion, but does not know how to enter the code in my Activity.java!

For the model I'm using viewpager for me is complex.

I wonder how to enter the code the accordion in my Activity.

Here the code of my  DiferencialActivity.java:

```
package com.example.resina.e.marcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class DiferencialActivity extends Fragment {

    Button button1,button2;
    LinearLayout panel1,panel2;

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        DiferencialActivity f = new DiferencialActivity();

        return f;


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.diferencial_layout, null);

        return root;



    }



}
```

This is the code you need to enter into my  DiferencialActivity, so she can interpret the layout of the buttons defined for this activity:

```
package com.example.resina.e.marcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class teste extends Activity
{
      Button button1,button2;
      LinearLayout panel1,panel2;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.diferencial_layout);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);


        panel1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.panel1);
        panel2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.panel2);

        /*We make both the panels, by default, invisible to user
        and make them appear on button click event in follwing manner*/

        panel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        panel2.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    }


    public OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                  Button ClickedButton = (Button)v;

                  if(ClickedButton.getId()== button1.getId())
                  {
                            panel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          panel2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  }
                  else if(ClickedButton.getId()== button2.getId())
                  {
                        panel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    panel2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  }
            }
      };


}
```

How do I insert this code in my DiferencialActivity.java?

Comment: Did you use a language translator?  I think it might not have worked very well.  What do you mean "accordion view"?

Comment: Yes I used, sorry!

My English is bad. = /

Accordion view is this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161999/android-accordion-widget

The model I'm using is this:
http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=135a3549-5c9c-48c6-9219-6ddd7986b063