# Series of Spinner Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls, android-spinner

I have two spinners in my application. Lets name it as spinner one and spinner two. Spinner two is placed below spinner one lik this.[image: See image below]

Usually in android when i click on spinner1 an overlay appears showing list of items. At this time spinner 2 will be behind the overlay. But I dont want it to be like that. I want my spinner 2 also to be visible.

What I want is when I click on spinner 1 my spinner 2 has to move down below the overlay and appear lik the below image.[image]

Comment: You know that your spinner 1 size may be bigger than the screen height ans so that would not help you. And secondly, what good would it do?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is an accordion-style view instead.

Take a look at this, it might help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313432/1295906