# In android how to get transition on click like dropdown

Tags: android, transition

[image: Can any body explain this image please. what is the name of this action. When we click it transit below and show the details and on another click it becomes same as it was previous. Can anyone tell me the **name** also][image: After Clicking on first image button option]

Can any expert tell me how to achieve this which is available is given image description.Can any body explain this image please. what is the name of this action. When we click it transit below and show the details and on another click it becomes same as it was previous. Can anyone tell me the **name** also. If possible can you tell me also what is the **name** which is below in this activity like **Home** , **Order now** , **Contact**, **Gallery**. I don't know what to call this type of button.
**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Check this https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view

Comment: Thanks @jaydroider . I was searching for this only.

Comment: Just `Google` before you ask Question. it is good habit for you.

Comment: To be fair he may not know it was called an accordion. Googling something like drop down menu would more likely give you spinners than an accordion, which isn't what he wants.

Comment: Yeah @Maslada i don't know the name of accordion. And one more help i want what is called which is below of this screen in which **Home**, **Order now** are written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what is known as an accordion.

See here for answers and links to github projects that would help you.

[Android - accordion widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161999/android-accordion-widget)

Comment: what is called which is below of this screen in which **Home**, **Order now** etc are written

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use Latest Material Library.

Click Link [Material Design Github Library](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner)
Or Use ButterSpinner Use These Link

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1707

[Link 2](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/android-material-design-spinner-dropdown-example.html)

Comment: what is called which is below of this screen in which **Home**, **Order now** etc are written