# What Box like view should I use?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app using Android Studio, and I want to use some type of expandable box, where I'll have an indefinite number shown like in a stack, and when clicking on the left side icon, the selected box opens up to show more info.

The basic idea of what I'm searching for:
[image: basic idea of what I'm searching for]

Would anyone know about something like that??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it well, what you're looking for is a recyclerview (for the indefinite number of row) and an accordion widget to open close your content.

I will suggest your to look at these projects:

1. https://github.com/hgDendi/ExpandableRecyclerView
2. https://android.jlelse.eu/get-expandable-recyclerview-in-a-simple-way-8946046b4573

which present all requirements you need.

And here is an similar question/answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313432/6809926

The google search I made : android accordion recyclerview example.